# Why does variable assignment occur after a boolean test is performed in PHP?

Tags: php

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) && strlen($row['url_key']) > 4)
{
....
}
```

I expected this to assign the fetched array to `$row` then check the length of one of the elements in that array, but instead I get

"PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: row in /home/dwilkins/stage_image_update.php on line ..."

If `$row` wasn't assigned, I would expect the test to short circuit, and the length of the url key to not be tested.  I know that $row is being assigned, because when I take `&& strlen...` out, it functions normally.  So what is actually going on 'under the hood' that causes this behavior?  I looked at the PHP.net entry for [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), but I gained no insight into this.

Comment: `$row` doesn't exist until your `while` starts to loop.

Comment: When evaluated, I don't think `$row['url_key']` is assigned or the index does not yet exist. Also in the end, the last time it runs, there is no `$row`.

Comment: Try using parenthesis, `($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) && strlen($row['url_key']) > 4)`

Comment: @AlanMachado That's incorrect. It just needs parenthesis

Comment: @Twisty regarding the last time it runs, `$row` not being assigned will result in the loop ending, which is desired behavior

Comment: @DonRhummy no, that's not incorrect. Your statement doesn't invalidate mine. Building the correct precedence syntax will assign `$row` before AND comparison, which doesn't occurs in OP's code. Actually, what happens is *exactly* what I've told.

Comment: @AlanMachado No, even with that, `$row` is set prior to the loop starting and is available to be used within the condition statement, he just neglected to properly enclose it. If it was not available prior to the loop starting, then statements like this would be impossible: `while ( ( $row = readRow() ) !== null )`

Comment: @DonRhummy I think it's pointless since OP already selected an useful answer, but I have to leave it clearly. Your first sentence is the same thing I've said, and your second sentence with the example doesn't fit what we're discussing because I was referring to the `$row` that doesn't exist: the one after `&&` (which WILL do exist, if precedence enclosing is properly used)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&&` has higher [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `=`. You need to structure your expression accordingly (e.g. introducing parens to alter precedence). This is a very important fundamental concept to understand and be aware of.

Comment: I incorrectly wasn't considering "=" as an operator, if I had I would've seen the answer on the very page I referenced.  Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Operator precedence.

Wrap `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)` with parentheses and it will be fine.

```
($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) && strlen($row['url_key']) > 4
```

The way it is now it is interpreted as

```
$row = (mysqli_fetch_array($result) && strlen($row['url_key']) > 4)
                                              ^^^^^
                                              Undefined
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to declare variables in strict mode PHP before used in a loop or "if" statement when in strict error checking mode.  Doesn't really matter what you null you set them to as PHP will auto convert the type.

```
  $row = '';
```

or

```
  $row = null;
```

or

```
 $row = array(); //EMPTY ARRAY
```

or you can use

```
 settype($row, "null");
```